# Update Kentico document field regardless of versioning

Tags: kentico

I have a field on one of my base page types which I need to update programmatically from an external data feed, so that it can be included in my Smart Search index.

The documents are versioned, but I want to update the published value of this field regardless of checkout state, and obviously avoid any sort of overwrite when documents are checked in.

The field will not appear on the editor form -- or ideally, would conditionally display for Global Admins.

It appears that using the API to update the document without doing a `CheckOut` fails silently. However if I do a `Checkout`/`Update`/`CheckIn` on a checkout-out page, the author will lose their work I assume?

Any way to handle this "versionless" field via the Kentico data model and API?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way around updating checked out pages. You can update the page type table directly, but as you mentioned, it will be overwritten when they check in. You could update the version history I believe to make changes to the current data that is checked out, but again, I think that will be lost if the user cancels.

The only way I can think of to solve your issue is to create another table that maps the values you want to the page. Then you don't have to worry about the pages being checked out, you just need to grab the documentID or something. Since the value isn't displayed to the editor, you just have a field that does a lookup on this table.

Comment: I've tried this, but I need the data in my Smart Search index. I've tried adding a custom field via a `CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentEvents.GetContent.Execute` handler, but Smart Search queries don't seem to play nice with added fields.

Comment: Might have to create a custom search index then. Might be the easiest solution.

Comment: I am utilizing lots of fields from the documents in my search, and I'm not sure that would solve the query parsing issue I ran into, but potentially worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred and right way is using the API but as you stated, it causes problems if a user has something already checked out and working on it or it's in workflow and not published yet.

If the field you're updating is page type specific, there is one thing specifically I can think of and that's going directly to the database to the page type's database field and perform an update to that field.

**Note: this is not recommended unless you know specifically what you're doing and have done full testing on it**

The down side of going direct to the database is this will not update the current version since you're using check in/out and workflow.  You will also need to update the checked out and current version which means you need to:

1. Go to the Document itself in the `cms_documents` table and get the document you are working with.
2. Then using the fields `DocumentCheckedOutVersionHistoryID`  and `DocumentPublishedVersionHistoryID' you can get the version history IDs of the document from the`CMS_VersionHistory` table.
3. Then you can perform an update to the `CMS_VersionHistory` and your custom page type fields.
4. You will then need to look in the `CMS_WorkflowHistory` table and find out if that document is in workflow and in what step.
5. After you have that workflow history step, use the `VersionHistoryID` field to go back to the `CMS_VersionHistory` table and update that record with your data.

Again, not an elegant solution since you are using check in/out and workflow but after some trial and error and testing you should be able to figure it out.

**UPDATE**
You may also be able to add a custom table or some other linked database table which will allow you to create a global handler.  The linked table would be where you perform your updates via API and other calls without versioning or workflow.  Then when a user updates a specific page type you could do a check to see when the last time that linked table was updated and update the field(s) you need on update of that particular page (of course by node and document IDs).

Comment: Thanks. That's a lot of digging in the database (and requiring updates to some XML fields from what I've seen) but so far seems like the only solution. Seems like Kentico needs to consider the concept of unversioned fields.

Comment: How would you go about that @techphoria414? Have it specified per field in an object?  Just had another idea, check out the update.

Comment: Ahh I see Zach already suggested something on the line of the update I posted.

Comment: Yeah in Sitecore for example you have the concept of a "shared" field, which is not versioned or workflowed. It's a field-by-field setting.

Comment: And yeah probably going back to my original custom table approach, I think I have solved my indexing issue that took me away from it.

Comment: So that's a pretty good idea @techphoria414, if you haven't already, submit that idea on the Kentico Ideas board http://ideas.kentico.com

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you'll have to check it in and out with API. See examples [here](https://docs.kentico.com/api9/content-management/page-workflow-and-versioning#Pageworkflowandversioning-Updatingapagewiththeuseofcontentlocking).

Also you might need to publish it in order to reflect changes on the live site.

Comment: So what happens if an author already has the content checked out?

Comment: Nothing will happen as execution will stop @ if (!page.IsCheckedOut) line

Comment: This does not address my issue at all then. I know how to check out, but I need to update this field regardless.

Comment: You may try to check it in if it is checked out, however not sure if this is possible while it is checked out by another user.

Comment: Direct sql query into database will work regardless, however this is not recommended approach.